# Moshi fails on Kotlin lazy properties

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

When deserializing a class with Moshi it fails on `by lazy` property with error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No JsonAdapter for interface kotlin.Lazy annotated []
```

So I want to tell Moshi to ignore the property. The way to ignore this is apparently to use `@Transient` however that can only be used on a field - not a property.

So how to ignore Kotlin lazy properties when deserializing with Moshi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can annotate the delegate itself:

```
class Foo {
    @delegate:Transient
    val bar by lazy { true }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... while this does work, it turns out there is another problem with lazy properties that are not initialized when deserialized by Moshi (NullPointerException) due to not have a no-arg constructor. But that is a different question.

Comment: @GregEnnis did you ever figure out how to initialise delegated properties in classes instantiated by Moshi during deserialisation?

Comment: I dont think so. I really wish Moshi used something other than Transient, which carries a lot of other meanings along with it.

Comment: If this is till an issue, add KotlinJsonAdapterFactory to moshi builder when building adapter:

`Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build().adapter(MyClass::class.java)`